# updating data into pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

i have a many to many realtion and now i wana know how can i update my table with a form that user sends to app . here is my code
route :

```
Route::get('admin/client/assign','ClientController@assignsellman');
```

this is my controller

```
public function assignsellman(Client $client){
    $user = User::all();
    $client_list = Client::all();
    $client = Client::with('sellmanlist')->firstOrFail();
    $sellman = $request->input('sellman');
    $client_name = $request->input('client');
    $client->sellmanlist()->attach($sellman);
    $client->sellmanlist()->attach($client_name);
    $client->save();
    return view('admin.client.assign',compact('client_list','user'));

}
```

and finnaly the view :

```
 <form action="/admin/client/" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="client">مشتری</label>
                            <select class="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
                                    name="client">
                                @foreach($client_list as $client_lists)
                                    <option value="{{$client_lists->id}}">{{$client_lists->title}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                        <i class="icon-arrow-left7 mr-3 icon-3x" style="font-size: 130px"></i>
                        <h4>ارجاع به</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sellman">کارشناس فروش</label>
                                <select class="" tabindex="-1"
                                        aria-hidden="true" name="sellman">
                                    @foreach($user as $users)
                                        <option value="{{$users->id}}">{{$users->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">تایید</button>
            </form>
```

when i submit this form it redirects to a url like this 
?_method=PUT&_token=mvf0i2FaxSBhDdJroqD6L1901QdvcR4b3tmgwekw&client=3&sellman=3
and nothing just happens to database .any idea what is my fault ?

Comment: your route is invalid Route::put('admin/client/','ClientController@assignsellman');

Comment: ty doe should i change the method of my form too ? cause when i change my route to what u said i get the page not found error

Comment: add `action='post'` in from html and add new route `Route::put('admin/client/','ClientController@assignsellman');`

Comment: i think you need to read about methods, urls and etc. In your case you need 2 routes, first for return form, second to save data from form

Comment: hmm ty doe i will do it :) can u link me the documentation plz ? cause i didnt find that in laravel

Comment: @Farshad see my answer

Comment: @foreach($user as $users) it does not look normal, change to @foreach($users as $user) and in controller $users = User::all();/// compact('users');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need 2 routes, first for return form, second to save data from form.
Your routes:

```
Route::get('admin/client/assign','ClientController@assignsellman');
Route::post('admin/client/assign','ClientController@assignsellmanSave');
```

Controller:

```
public function assignsellman(Client $client)
{
   $user = User::all();
   $client_list = Client::all();

   return view('admin.client.assign',compact('client_list','user'));
}

public function assignsellmanSave(Client $client)
{
   $user = User::all();
   $client_list = Client::all();
   $client = Client::with('sellmanlist')->firstOrFail();
   $sellman = $request->input('sellman');
   $client->sellmanlist()->attach($sellman);
   $client->save();
   return view('admin.client.assign',compact('client_list','user'));
}
```

View:

```
<form action="/admin/client/assign" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="client">مشتری</label>
                        <select class="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
                                name="client">
                            @foreach($client_list as $client_lists)
                                <option value="{{$client_lists->id}}">{{$client_lists->title}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <i class="icon-arrow-left7 mr-3 icon-3x" style="font-size: 130px"></i>
                    <h4>ارجاع به</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sellman">کارشناس فروش</label>
                            <select class="" tabindex="-1"
                                    aria-hidden="true" name="sellman">
                                @foreach($user as $users)
                                    <option value="{{$users->id}}">{{$users->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">تایید</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Thanks @j.Doe it worked seems like i just messed up the route and i have to read them completely again .thanks you saved my a lot of time .

Comment: just one more strange thing i see !! any idea why every time it saved the data 2 times in database ? :|

Comment: @Farshad update code in controller, need to delete two rows

Comment: if i remove that two rows the client_id will remain 1 no matter what i chose in form :(

Comment: ok got that i had to pass the secound attribute as array to my atach method so it would be like this          $client->sellmanlist()->attach($sellman,['client_id' =>$client_name]);